# While loop giving different return and print results?

Tags: python

The below code is for a class exercise. We are trying to find the last position of the target string:

```
def find_last(search, target):
    count = 0
    while search.find(target, count) != -1:
        return search.find(target, count)
        count = count +1

print find_last('aaaabbaaabbbab', 'ab')
```

The answer should be `12` but if i run the code i get the answer `3`.

However, if i use this code:

```
def find_last(search, target):
    count = 0
    while search.find(target, count) != -1:
        print search.find(target, count)
        count = count +1

print find_last('aaaabbaaabbbab', 'ab')
```

I get this answer instead:

```
3 3 3 3 8 8 8 8 8 12 12 12 12 None
```

So, it looks like my function is finding the correct answer `12`, the question is why is it printing out `3`, which is the first result of the loop, and not `12` when i use the `return` statement?

Answer (score 2):

Read about the [`return` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return):

> `return` **leaves** the *current* function call with the expression list (or
>   None) as return value.

When you do:

```
while search.find(target, count) != -1:
        return search.find(target, count)
```

`return` returns the result and terminate the execution of the function `find_last`.

Just remove it and you'll be fine. Just don't forget to `return count` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `return` terminates the current function and returns the value. The looping stops right there when you get to `return` and the function `find_last` is exited.

Instead of returning inside the loop, you could store the value in a variable and return it after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`return` discards the remaining code in the current function and continues execution in the caller.

To see what's going on, run this:

```
def find_last(search, target):
    count = 0
    while search.find(target, count) != -1:
        print  search.find(target, count)
        return search.find(target, count)
        assert 0, 'unreached'
        count += 1

print find_last('aaaabbaaabbbab', 'ab')
```

It will print only `3` twice: once inside `find_last`, and once outside it.

Answer (score 0):

do you want this?

```
def find_last(search, target):
    if search.find(target, 0) != -1:
        count = len(search)
        while search.find(target, count) == -1:
            count -= 1
        return search.find(target, count)
    else:
        return None

print find_last('aaaabbaaabbbab', 'ab')
```